# Printer Paper Modes

Tags: printing

I am trying to optimize how something is printed (specifically, I am printing black labels on [Avery print-to-edge paper](http://www.avery.com/avery/en_us/Templates-%26-Software/Templates/Labels/Arched-Labels/Print_to_the_Edge-Arched-Labels_Microsoft-Word.htm?N=0&refchannel=c042fd03ab30a110VgnVCM1000002118140aRCRD)).

I have an HP 551DN Laser Printer with the following options:
[image]

Are there any resources available where can I find information on the implications of each of these options so that I can figure out the perfect settings to make my labels come out nicely?

Here are the two manuals - they list the options but do not explain them:

- http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02836895
- http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03036411

Comment: Have you looked a the [manual](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/manualsResults?sp4ts.oid=4184772&ac.admitted=1472130931613.1123376534.492883150)?

Comment: @CharlieRB - I have - the manual lists the options but does not explain what they mean.  I have updated the question with links -

Comment: Frankly, what you are asking is too broad. You have not told us what you are trying to accomplish/overcome other than *"figure out the perfect settings to make my labels come out nicely"*. That statement is too subjective to be helpful here. What issue are you trying to resolve? Does it not print to the edge? Is the print quality low? Does the paper curl?

Comment: I am trying to find resources for each of these settings so that I can figure out the settings myself.  The labels are designed for a laser printer, but when i print them on normal settings the ink scratches off easily.  When I use some of the preset paper types that are for very specific types of paper, it prints better but not perfectly (For instance, if I use the setting for "HP Cover Matte 200g").  Obviously that setting works for other paper than HP's - so I am trying to figure out how to make optimized settings for a brand that is not preconfigured.